# How to display MVC 3 unobtrusive validation errors ONLY in a summary or div

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, unobtrusive-validation

The project is MVC 3 with Razor views and JQuery unobtrusive validation. Our web pages are set up with the label above the textbox and the validation message falls under the textbox.  Usually the textbox is about 150px wide so the validation message tends to be rather narrow and tall.  It doesn't look nice.

I would prefer to utilize the Html.ValidationMessageFor helper to position all of the messages together at the top of the page, preferably in a bulleted list.  I haven't found a way to "turn off" the display of the messages that are next to the textboxes, although I can use a validation summary to catch the property errors on submit.

Many of the validations are occurring in popups and we are using Telerik for the popups.

I would prefer to avoid editing the open source js files, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `Html.ValidationMessageFor()`  items in your view => this will disable the messages appearing beside your textboxes.

Next, add `Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Your Message")` at the point that you want the bulleted list to appear (must be within the `using(html.BeginForm()` call).  The false in this Html Helper is an overload that instructs the summary to not exclude property errors.  For styling, you will need to do some CSS work.

Comment: Even without adding Html.ValidationMessageFor helpers, the messages still show next to the textboxes.  Or is there a setting that will turn that off?

Comment: @dewmangolf - Can you add an example portion of your view where you are outputting the textboxes and the surrounding code lines?

Comment: thanks for asking. I see now that the custom helper we are using has Html.ValidationMessageFor built in. Thanks.  Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using the `<%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>` markup. This creates what you're looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't hide the message next to the textbox and I don't want to show the message twice.